# Error installing Diesel CLI: cannot find -lmysqlclient

Tags: rust, mariadb, debian, rust-diesel-mysql

When I install Diesel CLI with the following command:

```bash
$ cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features mysql
```

I get the following error message:

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "/tmp/rustcabc6Bq/symbols.o" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/diesel-494aaabaf9c702d7.diesel.8a2a390e-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/diesel-494aaabaf9c702d7.diesel.8a2a390e-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/diesel-494aaabaf9c702d7.diesel.8a2a390e-cgu.10.rcgu.o" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/diesel-494aaabaf9c702d7.diesel.8a2a390e-cgu.11.rcgu.o" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/diesel-494aaabaf9c702d7.diesel.8a2a390e-cgu.12.rcgu.o" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/diesel-494aaabaf9c702d7.diesel.8a2a390e-cgu.13.rcgu.o" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/diesel-494aaabaf9c702d7.diesel.8a2a390e-cgu.14.rcgu.o" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/diesel-494aaabaf9c702d7.diesel.8a2a390e-cgu.15.rcgu.o" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/diesel-494aaabaf9c702d7.diesel.8a2a390e-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/diesel-494aaabaf9c702d7.diesel.8a2a390e-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/diesel-494aaabaf9c702d7.diesel.8a2a390e-cgu.4.rcgu.o" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/diesel-494aaabaf9c702d7.diesel.8a2a390e-cgu.5.rcgu.o" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/diesel-494aaabaf9c702d7.diesel.8a2a390e-cgu.6.rcgu.o" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/diesel-494aaabaf9c702d7.diesel.8a2a390e-cgu.7.rcgu.o" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/diesel-494aaabaf9c702d7.diesel.8a2a390e-cgu.8.rcgu.o" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/diesel-494aaabaf9c702d7.diesel.8a2a390e-cgu.9.rcgu.o" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/diesel-494aaabaf9c702d7.iocr4642wl1uaz4.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps" "-L" "/home/debian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libdiffy-f3ce65478c264464.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libansi_term-aa790b76ae1cbdd8.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libdotenvy-6af17b109f823ec0.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libchrono-f5a8fd6575116f8e.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libiana_time_zone-f282355f5a19e459.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libnum_integer-079dcb528f5592de.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libnum_traits-a0cffe81197bcaf2.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libserde_regex-de103698459278aa.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libregex-ea9936878ceec74d.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libaho_corasick-baf6425746e05480.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libmemchr-334520b8e1754272.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libregex_syntax-f642ac60d3546d15.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libheck-c7bd8a413ec0bbe7.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libclap_complete-931716c70511938a.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libdiesel_migrations-7378f0935d3b7989.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libmigrations_internals-10df43384f658bb7.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libtoml-5d4224ba74b0b364.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libdiesel-0877ec29477a0963.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libbyteorder-510ffc4e257f2d27.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/liburl-f5961914240ed46c.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libidna-1961aa20f6462edf.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libunicode_normalization-3da56b1975497527.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libtinyvec-fe6611990298c7f2.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libtinyvec_macros-bdf25bf92466fffb.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libunicode_bidi-e00a6a938f2b0aa7.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libform_urlencoded-43a4a1c3e9496d06.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libpercent_encoding-9d8c9b27d8ec2d84.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libmysqlclient_sys-a49dcd0bcac9b6cd.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libclap-c1c7e6eeb717d4bb.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libatty-741edf229a9e2154.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/liblibc-2a1213a99333562c.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libstrsim-0486e2960dda38b4.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libtermcolor-70c21c338d8d09ac.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libtextwrap-e6bd43e3780230b5.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libclap_lex-376292584c8ccdb8.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libos_str_bytes-f21eee77d421ab12.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libindexmap-10b0144a72e32dbe.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libhashbrown-3567001474a7e8b5.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libbitflags-26685d3681f76461.rlib" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/libserde-d58347e4da0d9375.rlib" "-Wl,--start-group" "/home/debian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-768f64e43b4091ca.rlib" "/home/debian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-e452821b696c9b27.rlib" "/home/debian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libobject-a7446c7f96188bd3.rlib" "/home/debian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libmemchr-c5a6ebfc774c23da.rlib" "/home/debian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libaddr2line-52a5740c11b991fe.rlib" "/home/debian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libgimli-b254c2999cf1d000.rlib" "/home/debian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-c967233557e70d8b.rlib" "/home/debian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd_detect-9bc99a923ffc9ef0.rlib" "/home/debian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-9e5758314f8e4741.rlib" "/home/debian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libminiz_oxide-c4df43510a6a6193.rlib" "/home/debian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libadler-7dac3bc9fba03bba.rlib" "/home/debian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-b4e4bff40f511247.rlib" "/home/debian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-4664da76290c7f3e.rlib" "/home/debian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-a0fa5affe9eeb5ca.rlib" "/home/debian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-0af00d708e07f561.rlib" "/home/debian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-f1846029b2b380e6.rlib" "/home/debian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-25593227eb86a313.rlib" "/home/debian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-5def185726e092ba.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "/home/debian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-8cbeb5ac4095b356.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lmysqlclient" "-lgcc_s" "-lutil" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lc" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-znoexecstack" "-L" "/home/debian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-o" "/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A/release/deps/diesel-494aaabaf9c702d7" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-zrelro,-znow" "-Wl,-O1" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


error: could not compile `diesel_cli` due to previous error
error: failed to compile `diesel_cli v2.0.0`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-installx3KK2A`
```

Output is from Debian (bullseye 11.5) running in a VM (UTM) on a Mac with M1 processor.

- `Linux debian 5.10.0-18-arm64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.140-1 (2022-09-02) aarch64 GNU/Linux`
- `rustc 1.64.0 (a55dd71d5 2022-09-19)`
- `diesel 2.0.0`

No MySql or MariaDB repositories configured.

Comment: Note this is mentioned in the [Getting Started](https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started) docs on the diesel site.

Comment: @Holloway That's true. But the docs weren't of much help for me, at the time I was reading it, as I was looking for a short answer and didn't found one. So I made one. Probably because I was tired of yak shaving any longer that day.

Answer (score 3):

The note in the error message tells: `cannot find -lmysqlclient`. The lib `libmysqlclient` seems to be missing.

You can verify this by running the command:

```bash
$ sudo find / -name *libmysqlclient* | egrep -v "tmp"
```

## Debian

Install the lib with:

```
$ sudo apt install libmariadb-dev-compat
```

Or when using MySQL repo:

```bash
$ sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev
```

## CentOS

Install the lib with:

```bash
$ sudo yum install mariadb-devel
```

Or when using MySQL repo:

```bash
$ sudo yum install mysql-community-devel
```